# PHP Slim framework database class not working

Tags: php, slim

I've been banging my head against this for hours yet I can't seem to figure out the issue, essentially I have a library file that gets called in all over the place and works everywhere fine except where i'm calling it in here.

I can get slim to work fine until I try access the db object and query anything? Im probably being dim but this is more or less exactly how it says to do it in the slim docs with a couple of extra lines thrown in so it doesn't make sense that it stops working.

```
    require_once "libary.php";
    require 'Slim/Slim.php';
    \Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

    $app = new \Slim\Slim();

    $app->get('/login/:username/:password', function ($username, $password) {
  //check the login details against the db...
    echo "I SEE THIS";
    $query = "select * from sometable";
    $db->query($query);
    echo "I DONT SEE THIS";

    });
    $app->run();
```

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled? You might be running into memory errors by selecting too much - try adding LIMIT 1 to the end of that query to debug

Comment: Hi mike, actually in the real code i'm selecting from a table that only has one row, good idea though funnily enough 2 months ago I literally spent an entire day before I realised I was running out of memory

Comment: Where is $db being set? It looks like you're not instantiating it, that could be the issue here.

Comment: Hi Phil, well my entire site would fall over if $db wasn't working its defined in the library.php

Comment: 1. Enable error reporting 2. Fix error.

Comment: Sorry I should have said, error reporting is on our logging subs output to different logs ie (warning,info,exceptions). Heres an interesting thing though if I var_dump $db before the $app->get definition it works fine, but from within it it is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the slow response, rather embarrassing but all that was needed was to insert one line of code into that inline function:

GLOBAL $db

I had assumed(incorrectly) that variable would be visible from within the function since it was defined in our library.

Thanks

Marc

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the using GLOBAL with the **use** keyword (PHP >= 5.3.0):

```
$app->get('/login/:username/:password', function ($userstrong textname, $password) use ($db) {
    //check the login details against the db...
    echo "I SEE THIS";
    $query = "select * from sometable";
    $db->query($query);
    echo "I DONT SEE THIS";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also inject your database into the app as singleton thus:

```
$app->container->singleton('db', function () use ($dbcfg){
    return new \myDatabaseClass($dbcfg);
});
```

and then it will always be available to you here:

```
$app->db->query();
```

See this for more details: http://docs.slimframework.com/#DI-Overview

Comment: Thanks for that this was a while ago so i've learned a lot more PHP since then, but thats still useful!